# How would pronogrades build embattlements?

Tags: anatomy, military-defense

While there have been a lot of designs for embattlements across times and cultures, there is onee constant I have noticed: They all share similar proportions. This appears to be related to the erect human form, as they provide shelter to such a shape

What proportions would a pronograde species build their embattlements in? The pronogrades are around 50% longer than they are tall, with their arms near the front and head raised above the body. They have a human level of intelligence, and the technology is around that of medieval times when embattlements were used

Comment: Use a less cryptic word for people who walk on four legs. You will get bad answers if the question is too much effort to understand.

Comment: @Daron Pronograde doesn't mean quadruped, it means having the body parallel to the ground (I.e. what this question is about)

Comment: For the purpose of the question they mean the same thing. If you have to explain it further then it is a bad choice of word.

Comment: @Daron No they don't. An upright quadruped like a minecraft creeper would be nothing to do with this question, whereas something like an insect would obviously be relevant

Comment: @Daron: If only there would be English dictionaries online. French has online dictionaries, German does, Italian does, even Romanian does. Why are there no English dictionaries online?

Comment: @IchthysKing I have no clue what you mean by "upright quadruped".

Comment: @IchthysKing Do you mean like a centaur?

Comment: @AlexP [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pronograde) works quite fine for English definitions :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The same**.

[image]

Normal battlements are even better for your crawlers than for standers, since the crawlers are protected when moving between the taller bits. The tall bits are still there since the crawlers need to prop themselves up to use and reload their blowguns. The tall bits protect them while they do that.

Comment: For completeness you could also note that this basic shape also works for Centaurs.

Comment: Shape definitely stays the same, but there's room for proportions to change - particularly if the species can't stand on hind legs to fire. A species shaped like crabs rather than centaurs/monkeys probably wants the high parts to cover their full body width/length, so could be 2x the width of the lower parts or more.

Answer (score 1):

Consider how snipers hide on a hill. That's what you'd be looking at. Low walls, but arrow slits wouldn't change, or the distance between crenellations. Those shapes are based on the kinetics of archery. You might have ramps up to the edge so they can keep their butts out of the way of other soliders running by, or maybe they lay in troughs, and the other soldiers hop from platform to platform.